# What is the correct syntax for specifying generic boundaries while inheriting from superclass in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I've encountered a problem.

The classes I have in reality are more complex, but here's the general outline. There's a class A:

```kotlin
open class A(
    val id: Any
)
```

And class B that bounds that `Any` to a more specific class:

```kotlin
class B<T>(
    val clazz: Class<T>,
    nonnull: T
) : A(nonnull)
```

But it won't compile as `T` is by default bounds to `Any?`, and class A has a non-nullable `Any`. And usually I'd write `where T : Any`, or even `where T : OneInterface, SecondInterface`. But it does not compile. I am sure I'm just writing something wrong way, but what?..

[image]

I've tried both googling and looking into the documentation, but I am not the master of Google-Fu, and documentation is silent on this matter. Both [Inheritance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html) and [Generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#generic-constraints) are easy to understand, but they lack this exact intersection of language syntax. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the constraint in a different place:

```
class B<T: Any>(
    val clazz: Class<T>,
    nonnull: T
) : A(nonnull)
```

Or

```
class B<T>(
    val clazz: Class<T>,
    nonnull: T
) : A(nonnull) where T: Any
```

I'd prefer the first one and only use `where` when you can't use it, e.g. for multiple constraints.

Comment: Omg, thanks. It was *this* simple. We have a rather long list of arguments, and it didn't occur to me I could put generic bounds after the superclass constructor callsite.

Answer (score 1):

Restrict T to not accept a nullable Any:

```
class B<T: Any>(
  ...
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. The problem is, we have a convention in our codebase to use `where` opposed to this way, as we pretty often use multiple-bounded generics. I probably should have specified it in the question, though.